# How do I detect when the user changes between inputs pressing 'tab' using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a view with a form. The form has many inputs, and I would need detect when the user moves between them (clicking or pressing 'tab').

For now I have this:

```
  $('input').on('click',function(){

       // Do something
  });
```

But I would need detect if the user focus on these input even if he doesn't use the mouse.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `focus`?

```
$('input').on('focus',function(){

   // Do something
 });
```

> The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.) and links (`<a href>`).

https://api.jquery.com/focus/

Answer (score 2):

For all text inputs inside the `form`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').on('focus blur', 'input', function () {
        // Handle event
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `focus` event instead of click:

```
$('input').on('focus',function(){
   // Do something
});
```